# Incement value of datetime field

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQLServer2008R2. I have a column called `RunningDate`.

What I want is if today I set value of `RunningDate` as `2013-08-13 00:00:00.000` then tomorrow it will be updated automatically as `2013-08-14 00:00:00.000`.

I know about `DATEADD` function but how to use it in above scenario?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If it's always up to date with the current date - why even store this at all??

Comment: Should the RunningDate apply only to new records in the table, or do you really intend to update existing records? In the former case, set the default value of the column to CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME)

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

**Option A**

Leave the RunningDate column out of your table and create a view instead. Add the RunningDate column to the view as `CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME)`.

**Option B**

Create a SQL Server Agent job that updates the table periodically at midnight. Remember to strip out the time portion of the date (for example using the casts in Option A), as you can never be sure that the statement runs exactly at 00:00:00.000.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
      ID INT PRIMARY KEY
    , RunningDate DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @temp (ID)
VALUES (1),(2),(3),(5),(8)

UPDATE tt
SET RunningDate = CAST(DATEADD(dd, t.rn, GETDATE()) AS DATE)
FROM @temp tt
JOIN (
    SELECT 
          ID
        , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 1/0) - 1
    FROM @temp
) t ON t.ID = tt.ID

SELECT * 
FROM @temp
```

Output -

```
ID          RunningDate
----------- -----------------------
1           2013-08-13 00:00:00.000
2           2013-08-14 00:00:00.000
3           2013-08-15 00:00:00.000
5           2013-08-16 00:00:00.000
8           2013-08-17 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: I dont want to update manually..can you tell me how to execute your query automatically?

Comment: Try to use daily schedule with `SQL Agent`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not adding it into a database if it's only one field. If you are going to use it in stored procedure then use

```
SELECT GETDATE()
```

OR

```
SELECT DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, '19000101', GETDATE()), '19000101');
```

to match or `DateTime.Now` in your code - If it's .NET. You will be adding a lot of overhead just by storing one entry into a table.

Comment: Okay, but you should still be able to calculate it and not need to store it.